# How to use lambda to compare size of files when the input is a list of files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, reduce

I have a function that gest 2 file paths:

```
def f(local, remote):
```

`remote` path can be a simple `a/b/c` or a bit more complex - `a*/b/c*`. If I want for example to check if `remote` files exist I can do that using `lambda`:

```
apply_on_star = lambda func, path : map(func, glob.glob(path)) if '*' in path else func(path)
# and call it with:
any(apply_on_star(os.path.isfile, remote_path))
```

However, if I want to check file's size, I'm using `os.stat(path).st_size` and that's I'm not sure how to insert into a `lambda`.

What I want in the end is something like this: `lambda compare_sizes file_A, file_B_may_contain_star : os.stat(file_A ).st_size == apply_on_star(os.stat.st_size, file_B_may_contain_star)`

where the inner `apply_on_star` would get the sizes of the each file in `file_B_may_contain_star` but that wouldn't work. Can `reduce` or `lambda` or something else be useful here or must I write it in a function?

*Just to clarify - I want to take 2 paths, A,B where B may contain '*' and check if size(A) == size(B) if B does not contain '*', else compare size(A) with each and one of size(glob.glob(B)). One option I think of, is compare all files in B using `reduce`, and then, if same, compare to A, but I don't know how to*

Comment: I hear it's a cardinal sin to try and cram all the things into a lambda. Why not just create a function?

Comment: seems neat I guess

Comment: The neatest way is to simply create a nested inner func then pass it. `lambda`s should really be limited to anonymous functions that are defined in the args of calls.

Comment: Yeah, in general it's discouraged to use a lambda if you're just assigning it to a variable to be used as a function. Just making a function is clearer and more supportable/extendable.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to get away with this is the [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) library (the backport of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in Python3's standard library). To get a file's size, you can do `Path('file').stat().st_size`, and it also supports Glob in the form of `Path('parent').glob('star_pattern')`.

So maybe something like

```
from pathlib2 import Path

def compare_sizes(file_a, file_b_may_glob):
    size_a = Path(file_a).stat().st_size
    sizes_b =[fp.stat().st_size for fp in Path().glob(file_b_may_glob)]
    return any(size_a==size_b in sizes_b)

# or, as a lambda
lambda file_a, file_b_may_glob: any(Path(file_a).stat().st_size == fp.stat().st_size for fp in Path().glob(file_b_may_glob))
```

Though I'm not sure how to test it against your example.